# windows phone app running in the background

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to create an app the runs in the background? If so is there any samples out there for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application in the foreground can continue to run when the phone screen is locked(not background but...) by setting the [PhoneApplicationService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property. By setting up your application to run when the phone screen is locked, a user is able to access the application quickly upon unlock. However, when your application runs under a locked screen, it could consume power outside of the user's control. For this reason, your application must minimize power usage when running under a locked screen

Answer (score 9):

In Windows Phone OS 7.1 you can actually use [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) now to perform tasks in the background.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> Scheduled Tasks and background agents allow an application to execute
>   code in the background, even when the application is not running in
>   the foreground. The different types of Scheduled Tasks are designed
>   for different types of background processing scenarios and therefore
>   have different behaviors and constraints.

You can use a PeriodicTask or ResourceIntensiveTasks. Read more about it in the MSDN article above.

And here's some sample code for you to integrate background agents into your existing app.
[Sample Code: Background Agents in Mango](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Get-to-Mango-5-Background-68509798)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no way to create application that runs in background.

Comment: No longer true when Mango comes out (scheduled for Fall 2011)

Answer (score 1):

True multitasking for 3rd party Windows Phone 7 apps will come as an OS upgrade later this year. However, unless the app has to absolutely run in the background (like Pandora etc.), we as developers share some responsibility in making our apps feel at home with the rest of the OS.

Windows Phone OS offers app developers chances to save state of their applications to give the end users the feeling that it never stopped running; this is essentially the same as in other mobile platforms. As your app is being deactivated/closed, you have the option to "Tombstone" your state so that your users can come back to just where they left with BackStack navigation or future launches. Channel 9 had a nice set of demos & labs around tombstoning, found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WP7TrainingCourse_ApplicationLifetimeWP7Lab).

Hope this helps!