# Permanent background task in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Looking into developing an app for WP7 that requires continous monitoring GPS position. From what I can read from some searching there are certain limits to WP7 background tasks. Only scheduled for execution every 30 minutes, run for no more than 25 seconds, etc.

I would like to know how to bypass these limitations to permanently run a background task capable of monitoring GPS in real-time. (Think of Google Latitude for instance.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136054/windows-phone-app-running-in-the-background

Comment: Thanks. The question is over a year old, and since then multitasking has come and people have started getting some experience around it and possibly found ways around the limits seemingly imposed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that unless your app is actually running on the phone.

No background task can be permanent on WP7.

Comment: Yes, so it may seem, but thats not what I asked for. I know it is possible to for instance send notifications to fire off some code that starts a foreground app under lockscreen. What I want is options, alternatives, solutions.

Comment: Currently there is no capable solution to bypass this limit. Some homebrew-apps like "BatteryMonitor" can change the background-task intervall to 10 minutes instead of 30, but your app wouldn't pass marketplace certification and the task is disabled after a restart of the phone. You may send push-notifications to your phone, but have to manually tap on them to launch your app and react to them. The main philosophy here is: If something should be done permanently (e.g. tracking GPS coordinates) the user has to do it actively in the foreground so he cannot "forget" about it.